# Bluetooth low energy starts twice or multiple times if previous connections fail

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an issue while trying to establish a BLE connection.
Every time I try to establish a new BLE connection and it fails, as soon as I get a successful connection I receive the text multiplied with the number of total tried connections.

For example, I fail to connect first time and at the secondtime if I succeed in establishing the connection, I receive all messages two times.

Here is a successful connection from the first time:

[image: A successful connection from the first time]

Here is a successful connection from second time (first failed), and all messages are multiplied two times:

[image: A successful connection from second time (first failed), and all messages are multiplied two times]

Comment: It looks like this is Android? Can you check the device you're connecting to to see if it is generating the duplicates?

Comment: Yes, it`s Android and I am connecting to a HM-10 ble module. I don`t know how could i check if it generates duplicates. But if the connection succeeded from the first time, it doesn`t send duplicaties.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889420/android-ble-resubscribing-to-characteristics/49892822#49892822?